# Python not finding module after installing with pip

Tags: python

I installed nba_api using pip install nba_api in the anaconda powershell prompt. It says that the requirement is already satisfied. I followed the path, and it is indeed there. However, when I try to import in spyder, it says No module named 'nba_api'

How do I fix this?

Comment: When you run `pip install`, are you using a virtual environment? And if you're not, is the pip you are running in the same folder as the version of Python your Spyder is using?

Comment: I'm very new to python, i'm not sure how to check? How do I know if I am using a virtual environment?